# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-a^2 x^2}}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+c}}\,dx $

Tags: integration, exponential-function

i am trying to solve the next integral:
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-a^2 x^2}}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+c}}\,dx \\
& {} \quad\end{align}
with $c>0$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ but i cannot quite do it.
We have two branches ($b+i\sqrt{c}$ and $b-i\sqrt{c}$)

my idea was to do it by residues in the positive semicircle and the circle around $b+i\sqrt{c}$ of radius $r \to 0$. However the function $e^{-z^2}=e^{-R^2e^{i2\theta}}$ is unbounded (as $R\to \infty$) for $\theta\in (\pi/4,3\pi/4)$

A friend recommended me to do it by Euler substitution but i'm not sure how to do it so i did 
\begin{align} \sqrt{x^2-2bx+(c+b^2)}=x+t \end{align}
\begin{align} x=\frac{c+b^2-t^2}{2(b+t)};  dx=\frac{-t^2-2bt-c-b^2}{2(b+t)^2} \end{align}
obtaining after some manipulation
\begin{align} \frac{-(t+b)e^{-a^2(\frac{c+b^2-t^2}{2(b+t)})^2}}{a^2(t^2+2bt+c+b^2)}+\frac{1}{a^2}\int_{}^{} (\frac{2c}{(t^2+2bt+c+b^2)^2}-\frac{1}{(t^2+2bt+c+b^2)})e^{-a^2(\frac{c+b^2-t^2}{2(b+t)})^2} \end{align}

how should i continue?
the only informations i have about the result is that i should obtain something with the error function (erf).
i'm also ok with approximations

Comment: There are two reasons for which contour integration as described in the OP fails.  First, the function $e^{-z^2}=e^{-R^2e^{i2\phi}}$ is unbounded (as $R\to \infty$) for $\phi \in (\pi/4,3\pi/4)$.  Second, there are no poles implicated in the integrand.  Rather, there are branch points, which would require choosing suitable branch cuts.

Comment: then i have two branches $ b+i\sqrt{c} $ and $ b-i\sqrt{c} $ which makes $ \frac{x\exp{-a^2x^2}}{\sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}} $                     if i choose the branch of $ b+i\sqrt{c} $ will the contour circle around this point be suitable?

Comment: And how do you propose to proceed with contour integration given the first issue in the prior comment?

Comment: i can't think of a suitable contour... should i just drop the idea of doing by residues? the only other ideas that i can think apart from residues is trying to find some substitution related to erf(x)

Comment: I don't believe that contour integration is viable.  Why do you believe that this integral has a closed-form solution?

Comment: i just assumed it was (i'm not mathematician so sorry for so many questions), but the same integral has been solve in a paper and it didn't mention any approximation done but also not explanation how. sorry to ask so much but do you have a hint of how should i proceed then?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question to include the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: i would be really interested to see the purposed closed form solution..

Comment: the initial equation has more terms and appears in a physics paper about plasma so there is no direct result showed for this integral but when you try the derivation to find the final expression you quicly find an integral of this form and the only thing i can say about the answer is that it involves the erf(x) function

Comment: Now way this closed form ,if existent, would only contain $\text{erf}'s$

Comment: yes there is also erf' in the final equation, but also erf because is a triple integral in the 3 velocities so after this i should again integrate in two other directions giving in the end terms with $\sqrt{erf-\frac{(erf(x)-xerf'(x))}{2x^2}}$, erf', $ \sqrt{ \frac{(erf(x)-xerf'(x))}{2x^2} }$ and $ \frac{(erf(x)-xerf'(x))}{2x^2}$